# ASP.net redirect user on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp.net-membership

Given my registration page:

```
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <span class="defHead">Thank You!</span><br /><br />
                    You are now registered on our system.<br /><br />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>

   </WizardSteps>

<CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="searchBtn" Width="120" Height="26" />
<ContinueButtonStyle CssClass="searchBtn" Width="120" Height="26" />
```

I want to redirect the user if a condition is met, and they are at the above step.  I've tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CompleteWizardStep1.Visible)
            {
                Response.Redirect("viewBasket.aspx?action=news");
            }
```

But with no luck!  Can't seem to find anything.

Comment: What actually happens?  Have you tried placing a breakpoint on Response.Redirect?

Comment: Updated question, took optional condition out to remove confusion.  As the code is above, it just displays the Thank You! step and doesn't redirect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out :)

On your create user wizard control add a reference to a function `OnCreatedUser`:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard
        id="CreateUserWizard1"
        Runat="server"
        OnCreatedUser="CreatedUser"
```

Then define in your code the functionality you wish to run:

```
protected void CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Response.Redirect("viewBasket.aspx?action=news");
  }
```

Note this will stop the user being logged into their account.  To keep the user logged in:

```
    protected void CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
                TextBox userNameTextBox = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
                MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userNameTextBox.Text);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userNameTextBox.Text, false);
                Response.Redirect("viewBasket.aspx?action=news");
      }
```